leaflet-src.js:1582 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
This is a really strange error I am getting when adding Leaflet marker(s) to my Vue.js App.
Below is the code I am using:
<LMarker
    v-for="listing in listings"
        :latlng="[listing.lat, listing.lon]"
>
    <ChildVue />   
</LMarker>

When I remove ChildVue, the code works perfectly.
When I add back in ChildVue, I get the below:
leaflet-src.js:1582 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')

It's odd because my ChildVue looks like this currently, with no calls to lat:
<template>
    <LPopup>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </LPopup>   
</template>

<script>
import { LPopup } from 'vue3-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

export default {
  components: {
    LPopup
  },
};
</script>

Why does adding this file lead to this error?
Also, when I put the code of ChildVue.vue into my parent, the code works perfectly fine...

One solution I found was to move LPopup into the parent file.
This worked...but I have no clue why this worked and the aforementioned code doesn't.
Workaround:
Parent:
<LMarker
    v-for="listing in listings"
        :latlng="[listing.lat, listing.lon]"
>
    <LPopup>
      <ChildVue />
    </LPopup> 
</LMarker>

Child:
<template>
   <p>Hello world!</p>
</template>

